# PHP CURL and ssl authentication basic

Tags: php, .net, ssl, curl, basic-authentication

I like to get content of file protected with authentication basic and ssl , using this code:

```
<?php

 $ch=curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://webservicexxx.com:60443/services.asmx?WSDL');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "MYLOGIN:MYPASSWORD");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   // no verify
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 print $buffer;

?>
```

But in the result, on my screen i haven't the content of the file that i woulk like to get, but i have this page :

```
Erreur HTTP 401.2 - Non autorisé : Accès refusé en raison de la configuration du serveur.
```

That means, that the authentication doesn't work. What can i do to get the content of the file ?

Comment: Make sure you have openssl installed on your server.

Answer (score 0):

curl 7.28.0 has a known bug. See [debian bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=690551)

7.28.1 bugfix release is not too far away.